# Navigate to another Page Ionic on IOS

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ios-universal-links

I have a Ionic Button, which register the User via Google Authentication and Firebase.

```
<ion-buttons end>
      <a href="#" (click)="GoogleAuth()" target="_blank">
        <img src="../../assets/signInButton.png">
      </a>
    </ion-buttons>
```

The Function is this:

```
  async GoogleAuth() {
    try {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      await this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

On Web everything works fine.

When I build the App for IOS it can´t be open.

Therefore I installed the Package '<universal-links>'. When installed it the Error Message was at first :

`<universal-links> tag is not set in the config.xml. Universal Links plugin is not going to work.`

So I edited my config File in my xcode Project:

```
<widget id="de.markb.drinktogether" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>DrinkTogether</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <universal-links>
        <host name="https://drink-together-3d735.firebaseapp.com">
            <path url="/__/auth/handler/*" />
        </host>
    </universal-links>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
```

After editing it and buidling the App again I get this Error:

```
IOS project Code Sign Entitlements now set to: DrinkTogether/Resources/DrinkTogether.entitlements
Entitlements file is not in references section, adding it
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/ul_web_hooks/ios/https:/drink-together-3d735.firebaseapp.com#apple-app-site-association'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2221:35)
    at saveContentToFile (/Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:118:8)
    at /Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:72:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at createNewAssociationFiles (/Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:70:27)
    at Object.generate (/Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:45:3)
    at activateUniversalLinksInIos (/Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/afterPrepareHook.js:85:29)
    at /Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/afterPrepareHook.js:50:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/markbaumann/Desktop/drink-together/ul_web_hooks/ios/https:/drink-together-3d735.firebaseapp.com#apple-app-site-association'
}
```

How can I open a external Link in IOS, that my users can register in my App via Google?

I expected it would open the default browser

Comment: https://zditect.com/blog/35294991.html

Comment: does not help, because i don´t have the specific url. This makes firebase in this case

Comment: I would not expect a pure web based solution to work in a hybrid native application. Maybe look at https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/building-a-ionic-firebase-app-step-by-step or https://devdactic.com/ionic-firebase-auth-upload or https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/tree/master/src/%40awesome-cordova-plugins/plugins/firebase-authentication ?

Comment: this is all with sign in with email. I want to use signin with google. If you want to use Google sign in, it will be redirected to another website, where google handle the authentication. This is why a Webbrowser is needed

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but it does not appear to require a website to "sign in with google" https://medium.com/@a_shokn/how-to-implement-google-sign-in-in-ionic-5-9b2dc1581dbf or maybe https://enappd.com/blog/implement-google-login-in-ionic-apps-using-firebase/147/ ?

Comment: Maggini just posting random articles online to get upvotes... cmon man, atleast point him in the right direction.... anyways What plugin are you using? You don't need to add universal links or any of the above. Heres a capacitor version that i use that works well and setup was simple. https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/tree/main/packages/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try using Capacitor Browser plugin:

Your button would call a method that calls the plugin. So in your template section:

```
<ion-button @click="login()">Login</ion-button>
```

And in your script section:

```
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';

async login() {
  // Build here the needed URL
  const url = 'https://drink-together-3d735.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler/';
  try {  
    await Browser.open({ url });
    Browser.addListener('browserFinished', () => {
      // Execute here something to check if the user is already logged in
      Browser.removeAllListeners();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Note that you don't have any control on what the user does once the browser is launched, so you should listen to the `browserFinished` event and then check if the user is already logged in.

Comment: I gave you a bountry of 50 reps :)